# ¿Se puede realizar un Post luego de otro Post? (Spring + Angular)

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Estoy practicando con **Spring Boot** & **Angular** y quería saber si se puede lograr lo especificado en el título, es decir, si se pueden realizar 2 Post (uno después del otro).

Lo que voy a mostrar es la problemática que estoy teniendo en un código más grande, pero decidí hacer otro proyecto más chico para tratar con el problema en sí (así poder avanzar en el primero). Por eso, paso a mostrar el contenido de este:

**.:BACKEND:.**

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "pedidos")
public class Pedido implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nombre_producto")
    private String nombreProducto;

    @Column(name = "precio_producto")
    private double precioProducto;
}

@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "facturas")
public class Factura implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "tipo_factura")
    private String tipoFactura;

    @Column(name = "fecha")
    private Date fecha;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_pedido")
    private Pedido pedido;
}

@Data
public class Compra {

    Pedido pedido;
}

@Data
public class CompraResponse {

    private final String numeroDeSeguimientoDelPedido;
}
```

Los **servicios**:

**PedidoService**

```
    // Este método es simplementa para generar una respuesta aleatoria:
    private String generateOrderTrackingNumber() {
        // Generar una UUID aleatoria (UUID version-4)
        // UUID -> Identifiador universalmente único.
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    @Transactional
    public CompraResponse realizarPedido(Compra compra) throws Exception {

        // Recuperar la información del pedido del DTO.
        Pedido pedido = compra.getPedido();
        pedidoRepository.save(pedido);

        String numeroDeSeguimiento = this.generateOrderTrackingNumber();
        return new CompraResponse(numeroDeSeguimiento);
    }
```

**FacturaService**:

```
    @Transactional
    public Factura save(Factura factura) throws Exception {
        try {
            return facturaRepository.save(factura);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**.:FRONTEND:.**

```
export class Pedido {

    id: number;
    nombreProducto: string;
    precioProducto: number;
}

export class Factura {

    id: number;
    tipoFactura: string;
    fecha: Date;

    pedido: Pedido;

}

export class Compra {

    pedido: Pedido;
}
```

**PedidoService**:

```
private compraUrl = 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/pedidos/compra';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 realizarCompra(compra: Compra): Observable<Compra> {
    return this.http.post<Compra>(this.compraUrl, compra);
  }
```

**FacturaService**:

```
  private facturasURL = 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/facturas/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  guardarFactura(factura: Factura): Observable<Factura> {
    try {
      return this.http.post<Factura>(this.facturasURL, factura);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

En **app.component.ts** y **app.component.html** aplico la lógica:

**Lógica**:

```
  factura: Factura = new Factura();
  pedido: Pedido = new Pedido();

  constructor(private pedidoService: PedidoService, private facturaService: FacturaService) { }

  onSubmit() {

    this.pedido.nombreProducto = "Plasma HD";
    this.pedido.precioProducto = 500000;

    this.factura.fecha = new Date();
    this.factura.tipoFactura = "C";

    let compra = new Compra();

    compra.pedido = this.pedido;

    this.pedidoService.realizarCompra(compra).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(compra.pedido);
      this.factura.pedido = compra.pedido; // Error aquí, me tira 'undefined'
      // Al tirarme error arriba, esto no se ejecuta:
      this.facturaService.guardarFactura(this.factura).subscribe(res => {
        console.log("Éxito!")
      })
    })
  }
```

**Vista**:

```
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
    (click)="onSubmit()">Generar Pedido/Factura</button>
</div>
```

El **problema** es que no puedo **guardar** el **ID** que se genera del **nuevo** **pedido** en la **factura**. Creo que la problemática es ahí, ya que el pedido es generado y guardado en la base de datos, mientras que los datos de la factura no.

Desde ya agradezco cualquier tipo de consejo o ayuda, muchas gracias!

Comment: El metodo save te retorna la misma entidad que tratas de guardar pero con el id ya generado, puede hacer ```Pedido p =  pedidoRepository.save(pedido);```, de este modo,ahora inserta esa respuesta en la factura ```factura.setPedido(p);``` y en el mismo PedidoService importa el repository de factura para guardarla ahi mismo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Si quiero ingresar nuevos datos para la factura, los puedo hacer desde el Frontend? O en este caso solo del Backend

Comment: Lo puedes hacer desde el front, pero en este caso estarías actualizando la factura por lo que utilizarías el endpoint que solo usa ```facturaRepository.save(factura)```

Comment: ¿Agregar nuevos datos? Normalmente al generar una **factura** ya no deberías modificarla. Contablemente estaría muy mal. Una factura debe ser un documento final, cuya única forma de modificación sea mediante una operación de reverso o anulación, dando paso a la generación de un nuevo documento contable que sería la modificación del primero y que tenga su propio valor de `id`. Al menos IMHO es lo que debería hacerse.